# Url leading to archive page, no matter what

Tags: taxonomy

A client passed me a website I do not know how to fix: a specific url leads to an archive.php page, no matter what.
Say the url is 'classes', I created a page with /classes/ as url, but I get always the archive.php file.
I tried to inspect the functions.php file, with no avail.
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Is there a custom post type (like `class` or `classes`) registered by the theme or by a plugin?

Comment: @PatJ Yes there is, within the functions.php file, hooked to the 'init' event.

Comment: @PatJ  I unregistered the function, and now I get a 301 to the homepage. Almost done!